# How to filter for the special character "," in reports?

Tags: reporting, analytics, custom-reports

I want to create a report which will display the records in which the first name contains the special character such as ",". I added the above criteria as the `First name Contains ","` and clicked on "Run Report".  But the report was returning all the records. Is there any limitation of salesforce for filter criteria?

Note: The first name is a Text(50) field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're actually including quotes in order to filter when using a comma.

In other words, you should type in `","` instead of just `,`.

Correct:

[image: Correct filter]

Incorrect:

[image: Incorrect filter]

Also, read this [KB article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323721&type=1&mode=1) for more information.

Comment: Thank you...it worked... that's a great piece of information

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox. I am facing the same issue with the double quotes. I am not able to add it in the filter criteria. is there any workaround?